# SQL update column based on another table

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql, sql-server-2008-r2

Is there any way that you can update a table based on another table's column?

For example if I use the `AdventureWorks2008R2.Production.Product` table there are 500 products and each has an ID `ProductID` and Product number `ProductNumber`.

So if I have another table called `AdventureWorks2008R2.Production.ProductRev` and in that table the `ProductNumber` column has only 31 of those product numbers. Can I update the `AdventureWorks2008R2.Production.Product` to delete those product numbers where they match?

So AK-5381 from the `ProductRev` table would be used to delete the AK-5381 `ProductNumber` in the `AdventureWorks2008R2.Production.Product` table

[image]

[image]

Result would be:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Try this...

```
delete from p 
from [AdventureWorks2008R2].[Production].[Product] as p
inner join  [AdventureWorks2008R2].[Production].[ProductRev] as  pr on 
pr.ProductNumber=p.ProductNumber
```

Answer (score 1):

I believe this is what you are looking for... It deletes the rows in the `Product` table based on the successful `JOIN` with the `ProductRev` table on the basis of `ProductNumber` in each table.

```
DELETE P
    FROM AdventureWorks2008R2.Production.Product P
JOIN AdventureWorks2008R2.Production.ProductRev PR
    ON P.ProductNumber = PR.ProductNumber
```